# BouncyCastle (bc-sharp) decode DER formatted signature

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

How do I decode DER-formatted detached signature using BouncyCastle bc-sharp? For PEM-formatted signature I do it like this:

```
public static bool VerifyDetachedSignature(byte[] fileRawBytes, string sign)
        {
            try
            {
                var signatureFileRawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sign);
               
                var cms = new CmsSignedData(new CmsProcessableByteArray(fileRawBytes), signatureFileRawBytes);
                var signers = cms.GetSignerInfos();
                var certificates = cms.GetCertificates("Collection");
                var signerInfos = signers.GetSigners();

                foreach (SignerInformation info in signerInfos)
                {
                    var certList = new ArrayList(certificates.GetMatches(info.SignerID));
                    var cert = (X509Certificate)certList[0];
                    if (cert == null) throw new NullReferenceException();

                    var publicKey = cert.GetPublicKey();
                    info.Verify(publicKey);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

On rare ocasions I need to verify DER-formatted signature. It appears I just need to covert string to byte array, like this:

```
public static bool VerifyDetachedSignature(byte[] fileRawBytes, string sign)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] signatureFileRawBytes;
                try
                {
                    signatureFileRawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sign);
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    signatureFileRawBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sign);
                }
               
                var cms = new CmsSignedData(new CmsProcessableByteArray(fileRawBytes), signatureFileRawBytes);
                var signers = cms.GetSignerInfos();
                var certificates = cms.GetCertificates("Collection");
                var signerInfos = signers.GetSigners();

                foreach (SignerInformation info in signerInfos)
                {
                    var certList = new ArrayList(certificates.GetMatches(info.SignerID));
                    var cert = (X509Certificate)certList[0];
                    if (cert == null) throw new NullReferenceException();

                    var publicKey = cert.GetPublicKey();
                    info.Verify(publicKey);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In this case I get an exception on that line:

```
var cms = new CmsSignedData(new CmsProcessableByteArray(fileRawBytes), signatureFileRawBytes);
```

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=IOException reading content.
  Source=BouncyCastle
  StackTrace:
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsUtilities.ReadContentInfo(Asn1InputStream aIn)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsUtilities.ReadContentInfo(Stream input)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsSignedData..ctor(CmsProcessable signedContent, Byte[] sigBlock)
   at backend.Helpers.CryptoHelper.VerifyDetachedSignature(Byte[] fileRawBytes, String sign) in C:\Projects\[...]\Helpers\CryptoHelper.cs:line 107

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
EndOfStreamException: DEF length 63 object truncated by 2
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to decode DER-signature?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was not related to BouncyCastle. The problem was that I read binary data to a string variable and lose data. When i passed signature as byte array to `VerifyDetachedSignature(byte[] fileRawBytes, byte[] sign)` method it worked perfectly like this:

```
public static bool VerifyDetachedSignature(byte[] fileRawBytes, byte[] sign)
        {
            try
            {
                CmsSignedData cms;
                try
                {
                    cms = new CmsSignedData(new CmsProcessableByteArray(fileRawBytes), sign);
                }
                catch (CmsException)
                {
                    var strSign = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sign);
                    var decodedSignRawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strSign);
                    cms = new CmsSignedData(new CmsProcessableByteArray(fileRawBytes), decodedSignRawBytes);
                }
                var signers = cms.GetSignerInfos();
                var certificates = cms.GetCertificates("Collection");
                var signerInfos = signers.GetSigners();

                foreach (SignerInformation info in signerInfos)
                {
                    var certList = new ArrayList(certificates.GetMatches(info.SignerID));
                    var cert = (X509Certificate)certList[0];
                    if (cert == null) throw new NullReferenceException();
                    
                    var publicKey = cert.GetPublicKey();
                    info.Verify(publicKey);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps someone to not make the same mistake.